# Why roll a d6 when designing drugs?

Tags: cyberpunk-2020, medicine-and-drugs

I'm designing drugs, 'cause punk. (See Chapter 9: Drugs) I've chosen my effects, the drug's strength, and possibly even some side effects.

Now I choose my duration, which (if minutes or hours rather than turns) generates a multiplier to the drug's difficulty. But that section includes the following (p. 125):

> [...] When a drug is taken, roll 1D6+1 to determine the total amount
>   of time the drug will remain active in the system:
>
> \$\begin{array}{|l r|}
> \hline
> \text{1D10+1 turns} & \times 1 \\
> \text{1D10+1 minutes} & \times 2 \\
> \text{1D10+1 hours} & \times 3 \\
> \hline
> \end{array}
> \$

What am I rolling that 1D6 for?

(I suspect that two things are happening: the D10s in the table are typos and should be D6s, and the whole section's badly written: trying to capture both how long the drug will last *when administered* and what difficulty multiplier is applied to the drug's *creation*.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I can confirm is a typo, because in the spanish version of the game the table shows correctly 1D6 in the text and in the following table.

[image: Drugs spanish version]

Anyway, as soon as I arrive home I'm going to check the reprinted version of CP2020 of a few years ago.

**CHECKED**: On the reprinted version the typo still exists.